Azure DevOps custom extension - Rule evaluate engine throws error
In my custom azure devops extension, i sporadically have users reporting that the extension breaks and is not showing the data it should.
I am using:

azure-devops-extension-api: "^4.245.1"
azure-devops-extension-sdk: "^4.0.2"
azure-devops-node-api: "^14.1.0",
azure-devops-ui: "~2.164.0",

My manifest.json is the following:
{
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "lean-budget-group",
            "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group",
            "description": "Custom work item form group",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Lean Budget",
                "uri": "dist/WorkItemFormGroup/index.html",
                "height": 600
            }
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work_write"
    ]
}


When investigating in the browser console i see this error:
ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1 Error: Error occured in Rule Engine Evaluate. Name: undefined Message: Invalid node id. Rules.length: 2 Rules.Information: Block,Computed,-105,Required,,Trigger,-105 Stack: Error: Invalid node id.

With stacktrace:
at i._setFieldValueForce (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:88499)
    at a (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86623)
    at i.wrappedSetFieldValue (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86764)
    at i.setFieldValueById (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86256)
    at i.validate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:44239)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:37039)
    at Object._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:49535)
    at Object.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:48871)
    at i.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97783)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97667)
    at i._setFieldValueForce (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:88499)
    at a (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86623)
    at i.wrappedSetFieldValue (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86764)
    at i.setFieldValueById (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:86256)
    at i.validate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:44239)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:37039)
    at Object._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:49535)
    at Object.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:48871)
    at i.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97783)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97667)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:37257)
    at Object._evaluateFieldRule (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:49535)
    at Object.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:48871)
    at i.evaluateFields (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97783)
    at i.evaluate (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:97667)
    at i.load (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:108120)
    at new i (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:75609)
    at i.create (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:75760)
    at i.createAsync (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:76208)
    at async s.createWorkItemModel (ms.vss-work-web.work-item-model.es6.y_XqDY.min.js:1:127845)

When investigating further, i find that the error occurs in the method "_setFieldValueForce" with this specific line of code:
case r.CoreField.IterationId:
                    if (!(this._movingToNewIterationFixEnabled ? null === (s = this._nodeService) || void 0 === s ? void 0 : s.getNodeById(this.project.guid, t) : this.project.getNodeById(t)))
                        throw new Error(C.InvalidNodeId);

When in debugging mode and evaluating "s.getNodeById" i receive a valid result, but "this.project.getNodeBydId(t)" return undefined, and throws the error.
this._movingToNewIterationFixEnabled also evaluates to true, but i can find nothing about this variable anywhere on microsoft documentation.
Has anyone had any
I have updated the Azure SDK's npm packages, but since this behaviour only happens for some users, i am wary in changing too much.

Having the exact same error with a Custom Control too. It started happening a few months ago since when I finished the extension I had no errors on the console.
Funny thing, it only happens when I open the Work Item in the whole window (not the modal view).
If opened as a modal the error doesn't show.
Will look for info myself too, hope we can find something

Based on the description that some (not all) of your users encountered the Error occurred in Rule Engine Evaluate, you can review existing work item rules and see if any of them may have been restricting the modification of the work items by a group, like the sample here.

Unfortunately, not rules are defined for the work item type in the given process.

Can you share more details on the reproducing steps? You only shared a snippet of the extension code but according to your description. not all users could encounter this issue, then why you believe this was the issue from the code?

Sure, when i am logged in as a collectionAdmin user, the extension works without issues.
When i or other users are logged in as a user with Contributor access (Which 99% of users are) i get the above mentioned error.

By reproducing steps, did the issue happen as soon as the user logged in as a non coolectionAdmin? What were the operations that user had done? You can edit your original post to share the information. It is also suggested checking [here](the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#understand-roles-and-permission-levels-for-work-tracking) if your users are granted with sufficient permissions when attempting to do certain operations.
